# Win10 - add and remove icons from taskbar using regedit

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, automation

Is it possible to add and remove icons from the taskbar?

I have a program that installs a lot of programs and some are added to the taskbar and some are not.

I want to add and remove some automatically. I think maybe it can be done using regedit.

Comment: Have you investigated batch files?

Answer (score 2):

From the Windows Desktop, right-click the Taskbar and click Properties
In the Taskbar Properties window next to Notification area: click the Customize button.
In the Notification Area Icons screen that appears choose what icons you want to show in the Windows Notification Area.

This will allow you to hide icons and the notifications

or you could use this or play with this string this is where its located. 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer

EnableAutoTray DWORD

0 = On
1 = Off

Comment: I want it to be done automatic.

Comment: The OP has not asked about the notification area.